# Adding jars from EAR file to bash classpath

Tags: java, bash

I need to write a bash script for calling a certain java class. For properly running the script I need to add to the classpath some jars that are contained inside an EAR.

It seems that something like:

```
export CLASSPATH=E:/TEST/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/all/deploy/myEAR/*.jar;
java -cp $CLASSPATH com.util.DoStuff
```

does not work.

Is it possible to add such jars, contained in an EAR to the classpath ?

Using Java 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax is different in Bash Script, try

```
#!/bin/bash

CLASSPATH="E:/TEST/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/all/deploy/myEAR"
java -classpath $CLASSPATH com.util.DoStuff
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The syntax was actually from the homologous .bat file.

Comment: Why ? Even though you've corrected my syntax the above solution does not work.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.util.DoStuff

Comment: The .class file was generated?